# Is there any way to get Xcode app onto my iPhone without being a registered developer?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I'm learning developing for iPhone and I'm not registered as a apple developer. Is there any way how to get my app onto my (non-jailbroken) iphone to test it?

//I'm planing to register myself as developer little bit later. First I want to try some things and see the possibilities and so on...

Thanks!

Comment: No, there isn't. You can either pay for a cert or jailbreak.

Comment: you can "try things and see possibilities" in the simulator (for the most part) without being a paid developer.

Answer (score 0):

No,the only way around that is to use a jailbroken device and to "crack" your app. Rather undesirable.

You can ask someone with profile to add your device and give you certificate. You won't be able to publish your app or distributive. But you will be able to build on local device.